# how to conceptualize grouping in python logic statments

Tags: python, boolean, logic

No idea why this happens. Can anyone explain?

```
>>> foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> bar = [1, 2, 3]

>>> 'a' in (foo or bar)
True
>>> 'a' in (bar or foo)
False
```

I understand that python reads left to right, and that I should write out

```
>>> 'a' in foo or 'a' in bar
```

but what is going on in my test example? Why do I get True and False respectively?

Comment: What is most important thing to understand is  the expression in the parens is evaluated first and the in check  is done on the result of that. Without the parens `'a' in bar or foo ->  ['a', 'b', 'c']
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since foo is true, `foo or bar` returns `foo`:

```
>>> foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> bar = [1, 2, 3]
>>> (foo or bar)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

In a logical-or statement, evaluation can stop when the first true quantity is found.  So, once python evaluates `foo` as true, there is no need for it to consider `bar`.  Further, in a logical-or statement, python does not return True: it returns the first item that evaluates to True.

Likewise, since `bar` is true, `bar or foo` returns `bar`.  Order matters:

```
>>> bar or foo
[1, 2, 3]
```

As another example:

```
>>> False or 3 or 6
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason lies in how `a or b` works in Python. *If a is having value or is True, **a** will be returned else value of **b** is returned*. In your case:

```
>>> foo or bar
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> bar or foo
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to check the values in both the list, firstly make a single list with elements from both list by using `+` as:

```
>>> foo + bar
['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]
```

Then you can make your condition as:

```
>>> 'a' in (foo + bar)
True
>>> 'a' in (bar + foo)
True
```

Alternatively, you can also do it using `or` (without concatenating lists) as:

```
>>> 'a' in foo or 'a' in bar
True
```

Comment: You don't want to create a new list when you can just use or.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I think I was not clear with my words. Updated the answer

Comment: I mean, it makes more sense to use `if "a" in foo if  "a" in bar` , `bar + foo` would create a new list for every in check

Comment: Even I was also thinking about the same. Already updated the answer. `a+b` logic is based on what I think OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: You could also `any("a" in l for l in  (foo,  bar))` which would be nicer if you had more than two iterables to check.

Comment: In fact there are multiple ways to achieve that. One more: `'a' in itertools.chain(foo, bar)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123822/discussion-between-moinuddin-quadri-and-padraic-cunningham).